# How do I use lookup inside a list of objects with MongoDbB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So, I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
{
    things: [{
        details: ObjectId("id_from_things_database"),
        quantity: Number
    }]
}
```

So a list of objects that have details (reference to other collection) and a quantity.  What I want to do is a lookup for the details, while leaving the quantity in place.  However, I cannot figure out how to do this.  Here is an example of what I have got so far.

```
{$lookup: {
    from: "things",
    localField: "things.details",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "things.details"
}},
```

I can't figure out how to lookup that field in the array and maintain the quantity field.  I always end up with things.details being an array.  Any help is appreciated.

Ideal output:

```
{
    things: [{
        detailField1: "something",
        detailField2: "something else",
        quantity: 5
    }]
}
```

Also ok output:

```
{
    things: [{
        details:{
            detailField1: "something",
            detailField2: "something else",
        },
        quantity: 5
    }]
}
```

Comment: Actual issue is not with `$lookup` - which is working fine !! But the issue is with merging results of `$lookup` with actual document which is right here :: `as: "things.details"` it's overriding existing `things` field with result of `$lookup` stage.

Comment: Ya, I understand that.  I am just trying to figure out how to accomplish what I am trying to do.  I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `$unwind` before the `$lookup`.

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$things"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "things",
        localField: "things.details",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "things.details"
    }},
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", things: { $push: "$things" } }  }
])
```

you'll get something like that.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e8ec3c8005e625a6237d2e4"),
"things" : [ 
    {
        "details" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5e8ec370005e625a6237d2e2"),
                "name" : "Test1",
                "detail1" : "d1",
                "detail2" : "d2"
            }
        ],
        "quantity" : 7.0
    }
]
```

}

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array) they say "Starting MongoDB 3.4, if the localField is an array, you can match the array elements against a scalar foreignField without needing an $unwind stage."

Comment: @Ramesh : Serkan is right, I think you've overlooked actual question. Yes user needs to unwind in-order to solve his issue (which is not recommended on huge datasets though !!), but this answer lacks of re-grouping document (As we've exploded one doc into multiple by unwinding `things` array)

Comment: whoami is right.  This gets me closer and I will play with it (maybe merging again somehow?), but it isn't quite the output I'm looking for.  I will edit my post with desired output.

Comment: @whoami You say that this is not recommend on huge datasets, the things array will never be huge, maybe a couple hundred at most.  I am using this in Node.js.  Might I be better to try to get 2 arrays and then manually merge them together with JavaScript?

Comment: @LeeMorgan I made an update. For the expected result you also need to use $group after the $lookup

Comment: @LeeMorgan : Check out your query performance & then you can decide whether to do it in code or in query..